# OnDragListener being triggered without moving

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, textview, onlongclicklistener

Component 1 is a textview which has a LongClickListener.
Component 2 is a recyclerview which has an OnDragListener. The problem now is that when I click on my textview without moving the mouse the clicklistener is triggered but so is the ondraglistener for the recyclerview. Have I missed something in the documentation or what could I be missing here? As far as my knowledge goes the OnDragListener shouldn't be triggered at all especially when the mouse isn't moving at all.

[image]